# Can someone please explain why my flutter code doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter

```
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "No Transactions Yet!!",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                    height: 240,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/wait.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

this is a part of my flutter code, I have downloaded a png file and edited that picture so that it can have white background, now my problem is, it is not getting matched with the background of my App's Background (background color is white) . It is like a pasted picture onto the screen . How to fix this.
I am giving the picture try to see that in different directions so that you can understand my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhmnD.png)

I have tried like this

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/wait.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
```

here the photo was zoomed in.

Comment: Change the value of `backgroundColor` among `Scaffold` parameters to the same value.

Comment: i can see 2 options here .

1.Try to change the backgroundColor of the scaffold to the same color of the image background like @Jungwon said.

2.Edit the image to transparent png or svg.

Answer (score 1):

seems now ur background color is `Color(0xfffefefe)` change it to `Color(0xffffffff)`

```
 Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
      body:.....
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to set your Scaffold background color to Colors.white.

```
Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Colors.white
 body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
     SizedBox(height: 10),
     Text(
       "No Transactions Yet!!",
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
     ),
     SizedBox(
       height: 20,
     ),
     Container(
       alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
       height: 240,
       child: Image.asset('assets/images/wait.png',
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
     ),
   ],
 )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

change the background color to white in scaffold